# Sed - Replace text with ">" symbol

Tags: bash, sed

**Problem to solve**

Add ">" symbol in the replacement portion of a sed statement.

**Output Needed**

```
PS1=AccountName>
```

**Failed Attempt**

```
sed -i -e "41s/$/\n PS1\=${abasicstring}\>" /etc/bashrc
```

**Explanation of Attempt Values**

`41s` --> find 41st row

`$` = regex select the end of the row

`\n` = Add new line

`PS1\=${abasicstring}` -->  Adds PS1=AccountName

`\>` --> My attempt to escape >

Comment: If you want to add a new line to a file, use `41a`, not `41s`

Comment: You don't need to escape `=` or `>` in the replacement string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `a` command to add a new line.

```
sed -i -e "41 a PS1='${abasicstring}>'" /etc/bashrc
```

Comment: That works perfectly, but I am getting an error. LINE1: "bash: /etc/bashrc: line 42: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'  LINE2: bash: /etc/bashrc: line 42: `PS1=TESTING>' ----- EDIT: the value had to be in quotations. Nevermind. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: You need quotes around the value because `>` has special meaning in the shell.